# How do I change the .bst file to return both Editor and Author into my bibliography?

Tags: bibtex, jabref, custom-bib

I want to cite a few books which were edited/translated which means, I want both the author and the editor to appear in the bibliography. How do I cite them properly using:

```
\bibliography{sources}?
```

So far, I created my own .bst file using

```
latex makebst
```

and implemented it using

```
\bibliographystyle{custom_style}.
```

I created the library in jabref. As I said, a few of the cited books have both an author and an editor/translator.
During compilation, Latex throws errors like "can't use both author and editor field in [key]".

How do I force latex to add an editor to the output?

Edit: It appears that I might have to change the .bst file: http://www.verycomputer.com/18_e96f98b02315074c_1.htm

For now, the .bst file looks like:

```
FUNCTION {book}
{ output.bibitem
  author empty$
    { format.editors "author and editor" output.check
      add.colon
    }
    { format.authors output.nonnull
      add.colon
      crossref missing$
        { "author and editor" editor either.or.check }
        'skip$
      if$
    }
  if$
  new.block
  format.btitle "title" output.check
  crossref missing$
    { format.bvolume output
      new.block
      format.number.series output
      new.sentence
      format.publisher.address output
    }
    {
      new.block
      format.book.crossref output.nonnull
    }
  if$
  format.edition output
  format.date "year" output.check
  new.block
  format.url output
  new.block
  format.note output
  fin.entry
}
```

Any suggestions what to do? I guess I'll have to change something in the "author empty" line, because I want the editor always to be displayed, not only if there's no author. However, once I just change

```
    { format.authors output.nonnull
      add.colon
      crossref missing$
        { "author and editor" editor either.or.check }
        'skip$
      if$
    }
```

to

```
    {
        %format.authors output.nonnull
        %add.colon
        %crossref missing$
            %{ "author and editor" editor either.or.check }
                %'skip$
        %if$
    editor empty$
        {
        format.authors output.nonnull
            add.colon
            crossref missing$
                { "author and editor" editor either.or.check }
                'skip$
            if$
        }
        {
        format.authors format.editors output.nonnull
            add.colon
            crossref missing$
                { "author and editor" editor either.or.check }
                'skip$
            if$
        }
```

I get other error messages pointing to line 1565 in my .bst file, which is:

```
ITERATE {call.type$}
```

Any advices are very welcome.

Comment: What output would you like to see? "Anne Uthor (author) Edward Ditor (editor): *A Book*" or "Anne Uthor: *A Book*, edited by Edward Ditor", or ... `biblatex`'s standard styles allow for both an author and editor and would give you roughly the second option (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/35864)

Comment: I would prefer "Anne Uthor and Edward Ditor (Editor): _A Book_" as it is set up in "unsrtdin.bst", which is basically "unsrt.bst".

Comment: Ok, and what do you do if you have multiple editors and multiple authors? How can you tell which is which?

Comment: To be honest, I don't have multiple editors. That's why I didn't come across the conflict you implied. Probably I would do something like "Anne Uthor, William Riter, Edward Ditor (editor) and Thomas Ranslator (editor)".
But if there is no simple solution to that (which is weird, because there are a lot of books out there with both authors and editors), I'll just copy the editor to the list of authors with something like ''(editor)". Didn't think it would be that complicated :/

Comment: Can you upload your current `.bst` to a plain-text sharing website (pastebin, GitHub Gists, GitLab snippets, ...). That way I have something  concrete to play around with.

Comment: I followed your advice and chose the "edited by ..." version. Thanks! The files are in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I was able to get (almost) what I wanted.

Here is the new .bst file: https://pastebin.com/qsw2HziY

And here is the old one: https://pastebin.com/PPZ92dJQ

What I did: I changed my mind and wanted to get the reference:

`"F. A. Uthor and S. A. Uthor: A book (edited by F. E. Ditor and S. E. Ditor)"`

Then I changed the .dbj file which was created by `makebst` to present the editors of `incollections` the way I mentioned:

```
%<<EDITOR IN COLLECTIONS:
%    %: (def) Same as for edited book (names before booktitle)
% edby,%: In booktitle, edited by ..  (where .. is names)
 edby-par,%: In booktitle (edited by ..) 
% edby-parc,%: In booktitle, (edited by ..) 
% edby,edbyx,%: In booktitle, editor .. 
% edby,edbyw,%: In booktitle, (editor) .. 
% edby-par,edbyx,%: In booktitle (editor..) 
% edby-parc,edbyx,%: In booktitle, (editor..) 
% edby,edbyy,%: In booktitle, .., editor 
% edby-par,edbyy,%: In booktitle (.., editor)
```

And checked what this would change in the .bst file. Then I saw that the .bst file (in case of no author etc.) just changes the booktitle by appending `(edited by ...)` to it:

```
FUNCTION {incollection}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  add.colon
  new.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.block
  crossref missing$
    { format.in.ed.booktitle "booktitle" output.check %<-- this guy it is
      format.bvolume output
      format.number.series output
      format.chapter.pages output
      new.sentence
      format.publisher.address output
      format.edition output
      format.date "year" output.check
    }
    { format.incoll.inproc.crossref output.nonnull
      format.chapter.pages output
    }
  if$
  new.block
  format.url output
  new.block
  format.note output
  fin.entry
}
```

So I went to the function

```
FUNCTION {format.in.ed.booktitle}
{ format.booktitle duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    {
      editor "editor" format.names.ed duplicate$ empty$ 'pop$
        {
          bbl.edby %<-- this one inserts (edited by ...)
          " " * swap$ *
          "(" swap$ * ")" *
          swap$
          " " * swap$
          * }
      if$
      word.in swap$ * %<-- This line adds 'In: ' in front of the booktitle, dont need this in pure books
    }
  if$
}
```

And wrote a new function doing a similar thing (except the 'In: ' stuff):

```
FUNCTION {format.ed.btitle}
{ format.btitle duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    {
        editor "editor" format.names.ed duplicate$ empty$ 'pop$
            {
            bbl.edby
            " " * swap$ *
            "(" swap$ * ")" *
            swap$
            " " * swap$
            * }
        if$
        %word.in swap$ *
    }
    if$
}
```

Then I just replaced `format.btitle "title" output.check` in the {book} function with `format.ed.btitle "title" output.check`.
That's it!
However, the warnings about `can't use both author and editor fields in [key]` remain. Don't know how to remove them; it works anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this, is by adding editor information in an `\emph{}` environment after the title. For instance:

```
@book{abcd99a,
Address = {Ohio},
Author = {Arny, Anthony},
Date-Added = {2019-07-15 15:26:13 -0500},
Date-Modified = {2019-09-09 23:25:52 -0500},
Keywords = {Remember},
Publisher = {The Edwin Mellen Press},
Title = {On False and False Ideas. \emph{translated by Emacs Squared}},
Year = {1990}}
```